# Argument Labels '(_: RSKImageCropMode:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use [RSKImageCropper](https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSKImageCropper) library in swift (Library written in Objective-C).

I encounter the below error in my ViewController.swift file (see image).

Could someone please suggest how I could resolve this issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are too close to solved this you need to combine your comment code and current error getting code. So you need to initialized `RSKImageCropViewController` like this way.

```
let imageCropVC = RSKImageCropViewController(image: image, cropMode: .circle)
/access the imageCropVC
```